# No content length specified for stream data. Stream contents will be buffered in memory and could result in out of memory errors

Tags: amazon-s3, dataweave, mulesoft

I am using Mulesoft to generate an XML file and upload it into s3 bucket. However, I am getting this warning: No content length specified for stream data.  Stream contents will be buffered in memory and could result in out of memory errors.

Also, file size is less than 1 kb but it takes lot of time to upload in s3, I am using s3 create object connector.

When I upload same file manually in s3 it works well, do I need to set something in Mulesoft?

Comment: Please share the exact and complete warning message, and the XML representation of the flow. What generates the data being sent to S3? And also mention the exact versions of Mule Runtime and any connectors used.

Comment: This is resolved, there was a field in s3 bucket connector called content length, specifying that fixed it.

Comment: Please add it as a response to your question so others can benefit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there was a field in s3 bucket connector called content length, specifying that fixed it.